# Род и Склонение слов "Оттенков,. Фразы, Наречий"

Tags: грамматика

Какой род и склонение в слове:

1. Оттенков
2. Фразы
3. Наречий

Answer (score 1):

Род определяется только у существительных в ед.ч. им.падеже. 
1. Оттенок - муж.р.
2. Фраза - жен.р.
3. Наречие - ср.род.